# Consolidate 3 functions

Tags: jquery

Hi all wonder if someone can help me Consolidate the below code. i should be able to have less lines of code but not sure how to achive this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".question1").hover(function () {
    $(this).append('<div class="tooltip"><p>1This is a tooltip. It is typically used to explain something to a user without taking up space on the page.</p></div>');
  }, function () {
    $("div.tooltip").remove();
  });

  $(".question2").hover(function () {
    $(this).append('<div class="tooltip"><p>2This is a tooltip. It is typically used to explain something to a user without taking up space on the page.</p></div>');
  }, function () {
    $("div.tooltip").remove();
  });

  $(".question3").hover(function () {
    $(this).append('<div class="tooltip"><p>3This is a tooltip. It is typically used to explain something to a user without taking up space on the page.</p></div>');
  }, function () {
    $("div.tooltip").remove();
  });
});
```

Comment: You should use one of the many free tooltip libraries out there for jQuery...

Comment: If the code works and just needs consolidation, then it should be migrated to Code Review site.

Comment: (meagar) -> i always try to write ky own when its something as small as this, i think liabaries are a little overkill for such a small amount of code. (sparky) -> sorry yes this maybe should have gone into code review sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function setTooltipMessage ($elem, message) {
    $elem.hover(
        function () {
            $(this).append('<div class="tooltip"><p>'+message+'</p></div>');
        },
        function () {
            $("div.tooltip").remove();
        }
    );
}
```

Then :

```
setTooltipMessage($('.question1'), '1This is a tooltip. It is typically used to explain something to a user without taking up space on the page.');
setTooltipMessage($('.question2'), '2This is a tooltip. It is typically used to explain something to a user without taking up space on the page.');
setTooltipMessage($('.question3'), '3This is a tooltip. It is typically used to explain something to a user without taking up space on the page.');
```

And as @geedubb pointed out, you can use this function inside a loop

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding to this question, ill have a look at thos one, it looks like exactly what i want. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You could use a loop?

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        for(var i = 1; i < 4; i++)
        {
      $(".question" + i).hover(function () {
        $(this).append('<div class="tooltip"><p>' + i + 'This is a tooltip. It is typically used to explain something to a user without taking up space on the page.</p></div>');
      }, function () {
        $("div.tooltip").remove();
      });
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('[class^="question"]').hover(function() {
        $(this).append('<div class="tooltip"><p>1This is a tooltip. It is typically used to explain something to a user without taking up space on the page.</p></div>');
    }, function() {
        $('.tooltip').remove();
    });
});
```

This is much more scalable.

Comment: The tooltip message should be different on each tooltip, however

Comment: That would be easy to do, you can still get the class number and use it to identify which tooltip to load.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this.

```
$('.question1, .question2, .question3').hover(function() {
    var question = $(this);
    $('<div/>', {
        'class': 'tooltip',
        'html': '<p>'+ question.data('tooltip') +'</p>'
    }).appendTo(question);
}, function() {
    $(this).find('.tooltip').remove();
});
```

In your markup you can specify the content appended to each tooltip like this.

```
<div class="question1" data-tooltip="1This is a tooltip. It is typically used to explain something to a user without taking up space on the page."></div>
```

Comment: thank you for this, the problem is i need <a>links in my tool tip so dont think this one will work. Ta